# Android : I only facing difficulties in getting numbers from textView and putting it into int[]items

Tags: android

```
String numString = tv1.getText().toString();

int[] items = { 0, 5, -1, 2, 3, 9, 7, 12, 5, 4 };
```

Instead of `0, 5, -1` I want to insert numbers from numString which intern taking numbers from textView tv1.

I want to implement quickSort on those numbers. I only facing problem in getting numbers from textView and putting it into `int[]items`.

Comment: post your code for analysis

Answer (score 0):

To get text from TextView:

```
string input = tv1.getText().toString();
int value = Integer.valueOf(input);
items.put(value);
```